# SVG avoid partial pixels width and height with percentage layouts

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have SVG charts inside a complex grid layout. Users can resize, add and remove grids. I'm currently using flexbox with percentage layouts using flex-basis. What I've discovered is that because of the percentage layout, browsers are sizing my svg element to partial pixel width and heights. E.g. 1000.47px. The chart SVGs have been coded so they appear crisp. However, when the svg width/height has partial pixels they are no longer crisp and suffer from anti-aliasing.

I've tried:

1. Setting the svg to use shape-rendering="crisp-edges"
2. Using JavaScript and ResizeObserver to determine when the container changes and setting the width and height to full pixel values. This mostly works, but is causing other issues with the layout - I'm thinking because the child elements have an exact width/height, it is overriding the flex-basis percent?
3. Using JavaScript to determine the partial pixel size. E.g. 1000.47 - 1000 and using style="height: calc(100% - .47px)". This works in some scenarios but if the svg width/height has many decimal places it becomes unreliable. I'm guessing because of the rounding behaviour.

I'm starting to think a percentage based layout just wont work for my requirements (the above solutions seem pretty hacky) and moving to just using absolute/relative positioning to ensure the containers do not have partial pixels.

Is there no easy way to tell the browsers to use full pixel values for percentage based flexbox layouts?

Here is an example to try and explain the problem better as requested: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZXLrj

Whenever:

```
node.boundingClientRect().height; // or
node.boundingClientRect().width;
```

Return non-integer values, the SVG's start to be anti-aliased.

Comment: Without a [mcve] there is no way to test any potential solution. In its curent form, this question is unanswerable (except with a link to wikipedia's page on browser rendering engines, perhaps). It is therefore unlikely to be useful for future users and off-topic. Please add an example. A runnable, minimal, complete and verifiable one.

Comment: Sub-pixel rendering depends on the browser. IE for instance rounds to the nearest integer out of the box.

Comment: Thanks Philipp. I'm actually using electron, so chrome seems to not being using integral values. If there is a chrome specific solution to the problem, that would work.

Comment: Can you confirm you see these svgs blurry: https://jsfiddle.net/me6g13ws/ on Chrome. And if so, can you check the value of `chrome://flags/#enable-gpu-rasterization`. Sounds like you may be victim of [bug#945449](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=945449)

Comment: Weird. Those SVGs look fine for me (the site mentioned in the bug report didn't though). However I've tried disabling the enable-gpu-rasterization flag but I still have the problem.